# What is the simplest way to initialize a map, add a marker and then clear the marker?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

We have a page with a list of establishments.  There is a button that is labeled, "map".  When a user clicks on it, we have a Jquery Dialog window appearing and we have a Mapbox map appearing in that window with a single marker indicating the location of the establishment.

The issue is that the markers are not getting cleared out, so that by the third time a user clicks on the "map" button there are 3 markers on the map.

We are wondering

1. How to properly clear the map of all markers and
2. How to center the map on the marker

We are using the following:

Initializing map

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'our-map')
     .setView([49.2500, -123.1000], 9);
```

When a user click's on a button, this adds the marker to the map:

```
jQuery('.map-button').click(function(){              
    //jQuery(this.addClass("active"));
    var lat = jQuery(this).attr('data-lat');
    var long = jQuery(this).attr('data-long');
    var markerLayers = L.mapbox.markerLayer({
        // this feature is in the GeoJSON format: see geojson.org
        // for the full specification
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            // coordinates here are in longitude, latitude order because
            // x, y is the standard for GeoJSON and many formats
            coordinates: [long, lat ]
        },
        properties: {
            title: 'A Single Marker',
            description: 'Just one of me',
            // one can customize markers by adding simplestyle properties
            // http://mapbox.com/developers/simplestyle/
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-color': '#008000'
        }
    }).addTo(map);




 UPDATED CODE

    <script>
                var markerLayer = L.mapbox.markerLayer({ 
    type: 'FeatureCollection', 
    features: { 
    } 
    }).addTo(map); 
                  jQuery('.map-button').click(function(){

                    //jQuery(this.addClass("active"));
                    var lat = jQuery(this).attr('data-lat');
                    var long = jQuery(this).attr('data-long');


                 var geojson = [
     {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [long,lat]
      },
      "properties": {

        "marker-color": "#008000",
        "marker-size": "large",

      }
      }
     ];
      markerLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
      map.setView([long, lat ], 9);

                //map.setView([long, lat ], 9);
                    //alert(jQuery(this).attr('data-lat'));
                    })

                       jQuery('#dialog-modal').live("dialogclose", function(){
      //jQuery('.leaflet-marker-icon').hide();

      markerLayer.clearLayers();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the center of the map:

```
map.setView([long, lat ], 9);
```

And to clear the markers in a layer:

```
markerLayers.clearLayers();
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, 

Unfortunately, I am receiving an error in the console the markerLayers is not defined though.  Any ideas?

Comment: You are defining `markerLayers` in your click handler: you will need to define it outside of your click handler like `var markerLayers = L.mapbox.markerLayer()` and call `setGeoJSON()` on it in the click handler.

Comment: As for the setView, it doesn't seem to be working for me..looks like it zooms in really close on a random location...any ideas?

Comment: i have no markerlayer, i have added the marker directly to the map. how can i clear the map without having a specifiy layer-object?